# Could not find class 'org.restlet.resource.ClientResource', referenced from method com.android.navigation.MainActivity.onClick

Tags: android, build

I am getting this error in the logcat window. I have added all external .jar files in the build path. But I am not sure why this is thrown when I run the android project. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

}
public void onClick(View view) throws Exception {
double lat;
    double lon;
    String url = BASE_URL + "sites/" + SITE_ID + "/stations/" + STATION_MAC + "/";
    ClientResource itsClient = new ClientResource(url);
    itsClient.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    // Retrieve and parse the JSON representation
    JsonRepresentation jsonRep = new JsonRepresentation(itsClient.get());
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonRep.getJsonObject();
    // Output results
    lat=jsonObj.getJSONObject("loc").getDouble("lat");
    lon=jsonObj.getJSONObject("loc").getDouble("lng");
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:

        String lats = Double.toString(lat);
        text1.setText(lats);
        String lons = Double.toString(lon);
        text2.setText(lons);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this because I have added ClientResource in onClick method??

Comment: where you are setting your onclick listener? like some buttonobj.setOnClickListener(this); ? if you are getting any error please post with that error log, your question is not cleare enought to understand , and your code has lots of mistake if this is the complete code. you havent set any listeners. your onclik methode is now closed properly. post full code with error log it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: If I remove the importing of restlet packages, coding is working fine. Importing of Restlet is causing exception.